# Can I sell or swap Gwent cards?

Tags: the-witcher-3

I own multiple Gwent cards of the same type. How can I sell them or swap them for other cards?

How can I prevent to buy Gwent cards that I already have in my collection?

Comment: Note that there are reasons to have multiple cards of the same type - if it is a good card, having more in your deck is probably a good thing. And since you can't be a collectioner without being a player due to card getting mechanics I don't see how duplicates are a valid problem.

Comment: Duplicates are not a huge problem. But instead of having 4 x the same 1-point card without any additional value, I would like to trade it for 1 or 2 cards with a higher value or special function.I thought, one of the traders would exchange them.

Comment: I'm afraid, like in real-life TCGs, you can get many 'useless' or non-rare duplicates, and no-one in-game seems interested in taking them from you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You cannot currently sell or trade Gwent cards with anyone.

There is no current system for warning you that you already have a card in the Merchant interface (or any other item type). As you can use several of the same card in a deck (and can indeed benefit from cards with Link), it may be advantageous.

Comment: +1 for being right. I'm not sure, however, what you mean by there's no protections against buying multiples. If I'm interpreting what you said correctly, what you're experiencing is the way it's supposed to be, ie you get multiple copies of cards so you can put more than one in your deck. Otherwise you've hit I bug I didn't experience.

Comment: Ah, sorry. It was a slightly confused attempt to explain why you don't need multiple-purchase prevention for Gwent cards.